# send string to an existing form?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I understand that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259030/how-to-pass-string-value-from-one-form-to-another-forms-load-event-in-c) can send strings from one form to another. But if you look at the method, it has to create a new form where the strings will then be retrieved. Is there a way to pass the string to the existing form?

For example:

```
public class Form2
{
   ...
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(this.MyProperty);
   }
}
```

From Form1:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string departmentName = "IT";
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.MyProperty = departmentName;
    frm2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

When I click the button1, the new form in which the string are sent will be opened. What if `frm2` is already opened and I want the string to be passed to that form instead of a new one?

Comment: from another simple class  you mean ??

Comment: yes I assume each form has its own class

Comment: Questions should be self contained.  Please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: you can always use public properties and owner property of windows.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you'll have to save a reference to your form and then simply check whether it's existing already:

```
private Form2 myForm;

// Then, in your button code:
if (myForm == null)
    myForm = new Form2();

myForm.MyProperty = departmentName;
myForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property on the `Form1` class and use that as the reference to your `Form2`:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 mForm2 { get; set; }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string departmentName = "IT";
        if (mForm2 == null)
            mForm2 = new Form2();
        mForm2.MyProperty = departmentName;
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

}
```