# c# passing string to different form textbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, richtextbox

So, I have tried a few things that don't work but yeah. None of them work...
What I'm trying to do is pass a string value from one form to another, so basically you have the main form with basic controls and what I'm trying to do is log text to a richTextBox on a different form.
But I have no clue how to start with this.

Comment: Please offer us some code of what you have tried.  It will allow us to know what you're going and help us help you :)

Comment: You could also use google it which will point you to many different answers to this very question, some of which are already here on SO, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: make a public function in the child form that accepts a string value and sets the textbox text, then from the main form, you just have to call the function ... "form2.SetText("test");"

Comment: there are lots and lots and lots... of example of this. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259030/how-to-pass-string-value-from-one-form-to-another-forms-load-event-in-c

Comment: @HaukurHaf I have tried googling it, but I didn't find any clear answers.