# Getting and Setting variables across WPF Windows in Visual C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, syntax

I am trying to pass a variable `WorkOrderText` to a new Window after opening it. I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259030/how-to-pass-string-value-from-one-form-to-another-forms-load-event-in-c), however the variable value is not being displayed.

The Window where the variable is first set can be found here
    public string testingString;

```
    public partThreeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testingString = new TextRange(descriptionBox.Document.ContentStart, descriptionBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
        partFourWindow partFour = new partFourWindow();
        partFour.workOrderText = testingString;
        partFour.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
```

The Window that is receiving the variable and triyng to display can be found here:

```
 public string workOrderText { get; set; }

    public partFourWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }

    private void partFourWindow_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        testing.Text = this.workOrderText;

    }
```

But the text box shows up empty. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are doing this wrong. Changes in WPF should go throw a view model, the model, back to the other view model, and let INPC update the view. It sounds like a lot, but its *way* better in the long run. Research MVVM.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Looking into MVVM. New to WPF and Visual C#, so I have to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Shown` event is only available in WinForms [Form.Shown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is `partFourWindow_Shown` called anywhere? 
From the example code it's not being called. To get the text to update you can hook into the Loaded event of the window.

```
public partFourWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
     testing.Text = this.workOrderText;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I couldn't find a built in function for onLoad. Thanks for the help!